# Saving credentials in NSUserDefaults can cause app rejection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

I am a newbie at iOS development and I have used `NSUserDefaults` to save the username and password of the user.

I now know that I should be using Keychain instead of `NSUserDefaults` for this, but I don't have much time and need to publish the app ASAP.

I just want to know if there are chances that my app will get rejected because of this?

Comment: A deadline is no excuse for insecurely storing your users personal info.

Comment: @0x7fffffff No doubt you are right but that doesn't answer my question. :)

Comment: Is that *all* you're worried about? Is the idea of doing the right thing not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best thing to do, but it answers your question:
**Apple won't reject the app.**

I have published some apps that use NSUserDefaults to store user credentials. As you told, sometimes it is simply faster.

Just analyse how sensitive your app data should be. Most times the app won't need THAT MUCH security.

Answer (score 4):

There is almost no excuse not to use keychain, there are many wrapper libraries that make it very easy to use.  Apple is very protective of user's private information and could absolutely reject you for this.

- [`SFSHKeychainUtils`](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/) is a good one and here is a tutorial on it: http://gorgando.com/blog/tag/sfhfkeychainutils.
- [`Lockbox`](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox) is another good one.

Comment: Thanks for the straight forward answer, now I can't leave it as is. Thanks for the tutorial too.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to do this. There are dead simple keychain wrappers available on github:

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain

It takes 5 minutes to replace NSUserDefaults with one of above.